# Is there a way to make one column website layout responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, single-page-application

I'm trying to make the horizontal navigation bar on mobile and a vertical navigation bar on wider view-ports. It is a one column website layout.

I have tried but couldn't find a way.

```css
#main-nav {
  margin-top: 105px;
  margin-left: 300px
}

#main-nav a {
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 95px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav">
  <a href="#">home</a>
  <a href="#">about</a>
  <a href="#">contact</a>
  <a href="#">blog</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `media queries` to handle the positioning and also better if you could use `display: flex`.

This is a sample code I have done. The media query is set to a max-width of a tab device. Feel free to change it to a mobile size and test it. Hope it helps.

```css
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.main-nav a {
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 95px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

@media (max-width: 767px)
/* Set max-width in preference to your device. Currently set to tab size so if the page is viewed from a tab screen and below the menu will be shown vertically */

  {
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <a href="#">home</a>
  <a href="#">about</a>
  <a href="#">contact</a>
  <a href="#">blog</a>
</div>
```